# Input type number default 0 but if it starts start from 1 validation on submit

Tags: html, input

Hi there I have this case here:

```
<input class="form-control" name="example" type="number" min="1" step="0.01" value="{{ $example->something }}">
```

As you see I managed to do this to start from  1 and then to be 1.3 or whatever number greater than 1, by default is 0, I want it that way if user can let it 0, but when I submit it returns me with validation must me greater or equal than 1. How can I do this when user wants it 0 let it 0 otherwise start from 1

Comment: What about JavaScript?

Comment: how? I thought maybe if there is a solution without using javascript